# Regression Calculation, missing data

Tags: statistics, regression

In a regression calculation for five pairs of observations one pair of values was lost when data were filed. For the regression of $y$ on $x$ the equation was calculated as

$y=2x-0.1$

The four recorded pairs of values are:

$x: 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3$

$y: 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4$

Find the missing pair of values, using the following data for the four pairs above: $\sum x=1,\sum x^2 =0.3, \sum xy = 0.47, \sum y =1.5 $

The regression line was introduced before the introduction of the missing pair. The value of $b$ in the $y=a + bx$ equation is $1.9$ for four values of $x$ and $y$ and $a$ remains unaltered.

Further Mathematics Advanced Level, Statistics.

Thanks for help!

Comment: The regression line was estimated before the introduction of the missing pair?

Comment: @A.E Yes that's correct. Let me edit the question a little and add a bit more information.

Comment: @MichaelHardy This score was given by the authors. My own calculations also give 0.3.

Comment: @MichaelHardy just to clarify: $(0.1)^2 + (0.2)^2 + (0.4)^2 + (0.3)^2 = 0.3$

Comment: However you proceed, the missing pair is _gone_ and it cannot provide additional information. If you use the four $(x,Y)$ pairs you have to 'predict' an additional pair, you are just re-cycling information you already have, not recovering data that is lost. (Depending on how you do the prediction, you might even disturb the 'weighting' of the info you already have and get a less useful result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

Before loosing one pair, the linear regression to fit the function $y=ax+b$ (with 5 pairs) leads to the values of $a=2$ and $b=-0.1$ :
$$b=\frac{\sum y\sum x^2-\sum x\sum xy}{5\sum x^2-\left(\sum x\right)^2}$$
$$a=\frac{5\sum xy-\sum x\sum y}{5\sum x^2-\left(\sum x\right)^2}$$
Let $(X,Y)$ be the missing pair :
$$\sum x=1+X\quad;\quad \sum x^2=0.3+X^2\quad;\quad \sum xy=0.47+XY\quad;\quad \sum y=1.5+Y$$
The $\sum$ continues to be for the 5 pairs. Putting them into the above equations :
$$\begin{cases}
-0.1=\frac{(1.5+Y)(0.3+X^2)-(1+X)(0.47+XY)}{5(0.3+X^2)-\left(1+X\right)^2}\\ 
2=\frac{5(0.47+XY)-(1+X)(1.5+Y)}{5(0.3+X^2)-\left(1+X\right)^2}
\end{cases}$$
Solve this system of two equations for the two unknowns $X,Y$.

LATTER ADDIION :

The result of solving is $X=0.3$ , $Y=0.6$

A short way :

One observe that the pairs $(0.1,0.1)$ , $(0.2,0.3)$ , $(0.4,0.7)$ are exactly on the regression line $y=2x-0.1$

On the other hand, the pair $(0.3,0.4)$ is not on the regression line since the point should be $(0.3,0.5)$ to be on the regression line, because $2*0.3-0.1=0.5$

The missing pair $(X,Y)$ must compensate so that $(0.4+Y)/2=0.5 \quad\to\quad Y=0.6$

So, the result is $X=0.3$ , $Y=0.6$

Comment: A typo corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have earlier posted the question on cross validated (stats.stackexchange). With your permission I would like to share your answer there so that if anyone happens to stumble upon the stats page they can also see the solution there. Is that okay?

Comment: No problem. That's OK.